# Delete duplicate elements in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, I have an array like this;

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10]
```

If an element is repeated remove it completely

```
var arr = [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Any tips, link or code example would be useful.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What was the trouble that you had with the code that you tried?

Comment: whether the array will always be sorted

Comment: You should show your effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Filter out items with more than 1 index

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10];

arr = arr.filter(function (item, index, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(item) == arr.lastIndexOf(item);
});

arr

/*  returned value: (Array)
1,3,4,6,8,9
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what you need.

Comment: "arr.lastIndexOf(item)" should be "index", but even with the workload cut in half, this method is very slow. non filter methods are MUCH faster in my experience because you can keep track of the unique items in a new array instead of the whole old one. If your data can be object keys, that way is extremely fast because there's only one iteration.

Comment: @dandavis Don't think that would work `"arr.lastIndexOf(item)" should be "index",`.

Comment: @Xotic750: why not? [1,2,1,3,5,2,2,1,7].filter(function(a,b,c){return c.indexOf(a)==b;}) seems to...

Comment: @dandavis Because this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/Axq2h/) shows `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]` and not `1,3,4,6,8,9`

Comment: oops. misunderstood the goal. you're 100 right.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need for a library, ES ed 3 support is sufficient. If the array is sorted per the OP, then:

```
function removeDups(a) {
  var i = a.length && a.length - 1;
  while (i) {
    if (a[i] == a[--i]) {
      a.splice(i, 1);
    }
  }
  // Not required, but convenient
  return a;
}
```

#### Edit

To remove all duplicates "completely" with an unsorted array (works with primitive or object values), consider:

```
// Removes duplicated elements comlpetely,
// e.g. [1,1,2,3,3] => [2]
// Requires ES5 Array.prototype.indexOf
function removeDupsUnsorted(a) {
  var i = a.length;
  var idx, v;

  while (--i > -1) {
    v = a[i];
    idx = a.indexOf(v);

    if (idx != i) {

      do {
        a.splice(idx, 1);
        idx =  a.indexOf(v);
        i--;
      } while (idx != -1)
      ++i;
    }
  }
  return a;
}
```

Comment: And that was never answered by the OP :)

Comment: Always a fan of 1 function call vs 3 when using *filter* and *indexOf*.

Comment: This returns `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`. Yes, it removes dups, but the OP wants *only* the originally unique elements to remain.

Comment: Now it returns `[1,3,4,6,8,9]` as required, but uses *indexOf* (only as little as required). And the array need not be sorted.

Comment: Fyi as the array gets larger, the O(n) solution is faster: [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/10)

Comment: I initially considered using the same method as the *removeDups5* function but discarded it as it has some issues if you consider non–primitive values. E.g. `included[a[i]] = included[a[i]]=== undefined` should really be `included[a[i]] = a[i] in included` since *undefined* is likely a valid value. It will also fail where values are various types of Object (Object, Function, host object, etc.).

Comment: "...since undefined is likely a valid value" - agreed; excellent point. "It will also fail where values are various types of Object" - really? I'm not sure what you mean, could I trouble you to show one example?

Comment: All of our answers are guilty of making some assumptions about the OP's data, which could cause a possible incorrect answer, if the OP uses anything except "valid" or even negative numbers. Consider this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/RLYVT/) -> `[0,1,null,null,3,4,6] `

Comment: @Xotic750—methods using [*indexOf*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.14) use a [strict equality comparison](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.6) of values, so no, they will not fail if non–primitive or negative values are used. If you use values as Object property names (per the *noDups5* function) then you are comparing the result of *value.toString()*, which is why it fails with non–primitive values. `[0,1,null,null,3,4,6]` works just fine in the above (the *null* values are removed).

Answer (score 1):

Here is potentially an O(n) solution, assuming property lookup and insertion are O(1):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10];

var included = arr.reduce( function(a,b) {
    a[b] = a[b]===undefined; return a}, {} );

arr.filter( function(c) { return included[c]; } )
// [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

---

It is actually faster with direct `for` loops rather than `reduce` and `filter`:

```
function removeDups5(a) {
    var included = {}, i;
    for( i=0 ; i<a.length ; ++i ) included[a[i]] = a[i] in included;
    for( --i ; 0<=i ; --i ) if(included[a[i]]) a.splice(i,1);
    return a;
}
```

Here is a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/11) comparing some of these answers to each other. This solution is currently in the lead, it seems, the longer the array is. (Anyone feel free to add your solution to it.)

Comment: I wonder how that would compare against the `filter/indexOf` solutions?

Comment: @Xotic750 Good question. I've added a [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array) comparing these.

Comment: That's really not too shabby! :) I added my alternative to see how that faired too. :) [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/2)

Comment: @Xotic750 Nice; looks like you're in the lead :) (At least on my Safari - hard to tell overall.)

Comment: The amount of variation between browsers and versions always amazes me. :)

Comment: @Matt — [Check again](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/3). Plain ES ed 3 is seriously faster than the others.

Comment: @RobG Yes it's the fastest but it doesn't give the correct output.

Comment: @Matt—[now](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/3) it gives the right answer and is still very much faster (but uses indexOf).

Comment: @RobG Indeed it is. Link updated in answer.

Comment: Raw loops will always be much faster than the ES5 iteration (I would guess, though the gap has been closing slowly), as they don't do half the checks. But good job @RobG :)

Comment: I cleaned up the [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/6) to put all routines on a more level playfield, and used a large sparse array. Changes the view a little, while the raw loop remains fastest. :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Nice. I [added another test](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/8) `removeDups5` which is the same as my original but using `for` loops directly which is faster. I would like to understand why this is still slower than RobG's even though it is manifestly O(n) whereas RobG's is O(n^2) (unless object property read/write are not O(1)?)

Comment: Yours actually performs 2 full loops, RobGs 2nd loop is conditional, that would make some of the difference.

Comment: @Xotic750 Each call to `indexOf` is an O(n) operation. So even on the first iteration if `v` is unique, `a.indexOf(v)` has already done a complete loop through `a`. This is what I don't understand. Maybe there is such a difference between "hand-written" `for` loops and the "builtin" `indexOf` loops that even though in principle both are O(n), in practice the builtin loops are an order of magnitude faster (but then that's what I was trying with `reduce` and `filter`...)

Comment: Sometimes I feel like a blind man feeling his way through the dark. I think much would be better explained if I had an understanding of the tricks used when writing the JS engines themselves. I often find a `while` here or a `for` there can change performance dramatically one way or another, and what works in some instances then doesn't in others. Perhaps RobG can offer some insight.

Comment: Just to make it more confusing :) http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/9

Comment: @Xotic750 Ok [extending the array size to 110](http://jsperf.com/filter-out-unique-elements-in-a-sorted-array/10), now it is working as expected. The O(n) solution is the fastest, as expected. The Universe is back in order. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10];

arr = arr.filter(function (item, index, arr) {
    return arr.indexOf(item) == arr.lastIndexOf(item);
});

console.log(arr); // [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/YqufU/)**

Comment: Is that the same as `[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]`?

Comment: @Xotic750 lol misread the question :D

Comment: Why the two "indexOf" searches? you already have an `index` that's perfectly useful.

Comment: We need to use `indexOf` and `lastIndexOf` since  we need to check whether the first index of an element is also the last index index of an element or not. `index` will not work in this case.

Comment: And you got it right first. :)

Comment: @Xotic750 It's OK, the more important thing here is that we can help each other. Usually, I've received a lot of interesting and helpful tips and tricks here and there from other answers within the same question as well :)

Comment: Yeah I know, it's just the irony that I see repeated regularly :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Assuming arr is sorted, here is an O(n) solution.

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10]; //Make sure it's sorted!

var no_add;

var other = [];

other.push(arr[0]);

for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if(no_add == arr[i])
        continue;
    if(other[other.length - 1] == arr[i])
    {
        no_add = other.pop();
        continue;
    }   
    else
        other.push(arr[i]);

}

console.log(other); //[1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little tired, but this should also do the trick (ECMA5) and original order should not matter.

Javascript

```
var arr = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9, 10, 10];

arr = arr.filter(function (value, index, array) {
    return (!this[value] && array.lastIndexOf(value) === index) || !(this[value] = true);
}, {});

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
```

Output

```
[1,3,4,6,8,9]
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/G32VJ/)